# Howto Edit the billing name on a billing address

Tags: addresses

CiviCRM 5.16.3

In the billing address section on contact view, we can see a full Name and Address. When we edit or quick edit the contact, the full name is not seen or editable. How can we edit it?

Note: as to how that name is getting there, my current guess is via webform civicrm or an extension but I need to verify. I believe what is happening is someone is using another persons credit card to pay, and it's updating the billing address with that persons name. Then, when a receipt goes out in the future, some of our templates are pulling that instead of the billing name/address used in the checkout form (I think..)

Comment: You see a name in the address section? Is that name different than the name on the account?

Comment: Yes! For a billing address, and yes in some cases it's different when someone is using a card with a name different from their contact record.

Comment: Yep seeing it too. options would seem to be: 1/ check if it required by specific payment processor or not and if not then get rid of it for those processors, 2/ check if it is used other than in the receipt, 3/ get a UI so it can be edited if needed, 4/ decide to hide from the Contact screen even if it is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via settings at civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/address?reset=1

Look for the field = Address Name

in the section Address Editing

it can also be removed from display at same screen, look for Address Display and remove

{contact.address_name}